# how do i add delay to an if statement without pausing the whole program in processing

Tags: processing

I am making a platformer type game and need help on knowing how to delay the time before going downwards on the jump function i have tried the thread function and it didn't work I do have a question related to that but if there are any alternatives please let me know that would be very much appreciate it.

Comment: can you explain why you think you need to delay anything? If you're using normal physics, then your jump up and coming back down are simply a (parabolic) function of time relative to when you started jumping. There is no separate code for "starting to come back down", that's simply what happens because of maths.

Comment: What language or game engine are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [thread function wont work for the jump function in a game i am currently developing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924911/thread-function-wont-work-for-the-jump-function-in-a-game-i-am-currently-develop)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to delay something without stopping the program. It's a class I wrote a long time ago, when I was still a student, so I'm not proud of it but I think that it's a good way to introduce someone to [millis()](https://processing.org/reference/millis_.html).

Long story short, this class will let you enter a number of milliseconds it will wait for and you can, in your loop, test to see if the delay is expired or not. Here's the class:

```
class Delay {
  int limit;
  
  Delay (int l) {
    limit = millis() + l;
  }
  
  boolean expired () {  
    return millis() > limit;
  }
}
```

And here's an example of a program waiting 5000 millis (5 seconds) after a mouse click before letting you click again. It's pretty self-explanatory, but don't hesitate to ask questions about it:

```
int count;
Delay delay;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  delay = new Delay(0);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  // 
  if (!delay.expired()) {
    fill(color(255, 0, 0));
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    fill(0);
    text("Time before click is allowed: " + (delay.limit - millis()), 20, 20);
  }
  text("Time since last click: " + (millis() - count), 20, 40);
}

void mouseClicked() {
  // only lets you start a new delay if the last one is expired
  if (delay.expired()) {
    delay = new Delay(5000);
    count = millis();
  }
}

class Delay {
  int limit;

  Delay (int l) {
    limit = millis() + l;
  }

  boolean expired () {  
    return millis() > limit;
  }
}
```

Knowing how to time stuff is important, but timing stuff like jumps in a platformer often include other considerations, like touching the ground or not. Still, I hope that this will help you.

Have fun!